# Unable to run react native project in my mobile device

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to run my react native app in my mobile device by following the docs.
[https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vjtV.png)

I am using the command

> npx react-native run-android

But it is showing me the following error:

> error Android project not found. Are you sure this is a React Native
> project? If your Android files are located in a non-standard location
> (e.g. not inside 'android' folder), consider setting
> `project.android.sourceDir` option to point to a new location. info
> Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I am not understanding what does it mean by "android" folder? Because I already have an android folder in my project directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue please try these steps:

1- Clear `node_modules`.

2- add this to `package.json`

```
"resolutions": { "glob": "7.2.0" }
```

3- Reinstall node_modules with `npm install`

You can check this old question from [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33835) for more details.